# How do i create a odd/even colored list, with modulus in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

**Description**

I'm currently trying to use the modulus operator in JavaScript, to target a specific HTML list and make it so the items in there that are odd has X color and those who are even has Y color.

```js
function newFunction() {
  var items = document.getElementById("oddEven");
  var index = items.querySelectorAll("li");
  console.log(index);

  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    console.log(items[i]);
    if (i % 2 == 1) {
      document.getElementById("oddEven").style.color = "orange";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("oddEven").style.color = "blue";
    }
  }
}
newFunction();
```

```html
<ul id="oddEven">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

**Errors**
None in JSlint, IDE VS CODE, Console.

**Attempts**
I've searched around for similiar topics regarding modulus which there are a bunch of, but mostly all of them tend to be regarding background colors for completely different elements.
Even when i've replicated others code and just edited out the targeted elements, i simply can't get it to work.

**Question**
Is it that I'm using the for loop wrong here? Or is the modulus just completely off?
I thought about the "if" and "else" document.getX, perhaps that is used wrong..

Is there someone who coud give a fresh eye of where my code is wrong, or just a hint..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple things...

- The `index` selector would have worked in the loop, but that wasn't even being used, so I've removed it. I've combined the two with method chaining. You could simplify further with `document.querySelectorAll('#oddEven li')`.
- You were setting the class on the list rather than the item. I'm setting it by index from the selector list.

```js
function newFunction() {
  var items = document.getElementById("oddEven").querySelectorAll("li");

  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 1) {
      items[i].style.color = "orange";
    } else {
      items[i].style.color = "blue";
    }
  }
}
newFunction();
```

```html
<ul id="oddEven">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding an alternative, it iterates through a NodeList with `.forEach()` and uses ternary operators:

```
node.style.color = index === 0 || index % 2 === 0 ? colorEven : colorOdd;
```

The value of current node (element) is the color for even numbers IF index is 0
OR index can be divided by 2 evenly OTHERWISE, it's the color for odd numbers.

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll("li");

function stripes(nodeList, colorOdd, colorEven) {
  nodeList.forEach((node, index) => {
    node.style.color = index === 0 || index % 2 === 0 ? colorEven : colorOdd;
  });
}

stripes(items, 'orange', 'blue');
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than setting the `item.style.color` you would be better off adding a class to the list-item, like `item.classList.add('odd');` (or 'even') and styling `li.odd` and `li.even` the way you want.

```js
const oddEvenClasses = [ 'even', 'odd' ];

function newFunction() {
  var items = document.getElementById("oddEven").querySelectorAll("li");

  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].classList.add(oddEvenClasses[(i+1) % 2]);
  }
}
newFunction();
```

```css
li.even {
    color: orange;
}
li.odd {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul id="oddEven">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Of course — you could also do it with pure CSS and no JS needed, using a CSS selector `li` with [`nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type)

```css
ul.oddEven li:nth-of-type(2n) {
  color: orange;
}
ul.oddEven li:nth-of-type(2n+1) {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul class="oddEven">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```